# How to Play a video with multiple Resolutions using Shaka Player?

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, screen-resolution, mpeg-dash, shaka

I want to play a video with multiple Resolutions using Shaka Player. Single video with multiple qualities.

I have checked all the api's of shaka player. But I don't know how to do it.

I should have a video tag and I have to pass a DASH video.
My output should be a video tag which plays the same video with multiple Qualities like (1080p, 720p, 480p)

I need like this
[image: I need like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the information on how to do this in the Shaka documentation: 
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-ui-customization.html

```
const config = {
  'overflowMenuButtons' : ['quality']
}
ui.configure(config);
```

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? The mentioned code/url does not add the quality option to the main video controls as highlighted in the question. This feature is underway here: https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/2676

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the shaka ui library.

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Shaka Player ui compiled library: -->
    <!-- <script src="dist/shaka-player.ui.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/3.0.7/shaka-player.ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-KpD7UW8aOliftdEvclj0KBnwh6vKS708SS41xCNr11yjCSAcYxb4+tlaQTfK+GDw2VCv2DxiM2Zu1d3+WqXw+g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Shaka Player ui compiled library default CSS: -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/controls.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/3.0.7/controls.min.css" integrity="sha512-XLwXArwaPbtdmlcbaeNgSF3cBB4Q7T7ptfhEfpkDIc/gkvKk8S413yzTByJ7X9dgOZR/T7NxrQI0HE4hlc+2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- Chromecast SDK (if you want Chromecast support for your app): -->
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
    <!-- Your application source: -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The data-shaka-player-container tag will make the UI library place the controls in this div.
         The data-shaka-player-cast-receiver-id tag allows you to provide a Cast Application ID that
           the cast button will cast to; the value provided here is the sample cast receiver. -->
    <div data-shaka-player-container style="max-width:40em"
         data-shaka-player-cast-receiver-id="930DEB06">
       <!-- The data-shaka-player tag will make the UI library use this video element.
            If no video is provided, the UI will automatically make one inside the container div. -->
      <video autoplay data-shaka-player id="video" style="width:100%;height:100%"></video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
    const manifestUri =
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one/dash.mpd';
    // 'media/stream/0b97b1ef-a193-4ce7-8a0f-bca5a927a0f9.mpd';

    async function init() {
    // When using the UI, the player is made automatically by the UI object.
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const ui = video['ui'];
    const controls = ui.getControls();
    const player = controls.getPlayer();

    // Attach player and ui to the window to make it easy to access in the JS console.
    window.player = player;
    window.ui = ui;

    // Listen for error events.
    player.addEventListener('error', onPlayerErrorEvent);
    controls.addEventListener('error', onUIErrorEvent);

    // Try to load a manifest.
    // This is an asynchronous process.
    try {
        await player.load(manifestUri);
        // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
        console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
    } catch (error) {
        onPlayerError(error);
    }
    }

    function onPlayerErrorEvent(errorEvent) {
    // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
    onPlayerError(event.detail);
    }

    function onPlayerError(error) {
    // Handle player error
    console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);
    }

    function onUIErrorEvent(errorEvent) {
    // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
    onPlayerError(event.detail);
    }

    function initFailed(errorEvent) {
    // Handle the failure to load; errorEvent.detail.reasonCode has a
    // shaka.ui.FailReasonCode describing why.
    console.error('Unable to load the UI library!');
    }

    // Listen to the custom shaka-ui-loaded event, to wait until the UI is loaded.
    document.addEventListener('shaka-ui-loaded', init);
    // Listen to the custom shaka-ui-load-failed event, in case Shaka Player fails
    // to load (e.g. due to lack of browser support).
    document.addEventListener('shaka-ui-load-failed', initFailed);

</script>
```